# EU national entering in USA with a single vaccination shot

Tags: usa, paperwork, covid-19, spain, eu

A Spaniard friend of mine is planning to travel to the USA. He has the vaccination certificate saying that he is fully vaccinated.

The problem is that, in Spain (and perhaps other countries) for patients who have already been infected within 6 months they are giving them a single shot, instead of the two shots for vaccines that would normally requires two. This is an official policy with certain Scientist backing since those patients what they want is to boost their already acquired immunity.

In his documents he is described as fully vaccinated having 1/1 required shots. Speaking to higher representatives in his province, they explained that this is enough for traveling within Europe, but, they are unsure about USA.

**EDIT**

He is planning to come in December, meaning that by that time USA border will follow the new policy that allows EU citizens to visit USA as long as they are vaccinated.

Comment: As already mentioned, the wording of the new US rules are not yet known, but almost without exeption, it is the *accepting* country and not the *issuing* country which define the requirements to be counted as fully vaccinated and there are plenty of differences in the details even between European countries. I am pretty sure that there are European countries as well, who would not allow your friend to enter with a single vaccine shot, even though the Spanish authorities think differently.

Comment: Spain's policy is causing all sorts of issues by being out-of-step with much of the rest of the world; see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168287/12065) for a very similar issue with UK entry.

Comment: @MadHatter this is also the case of Germany (https://www.reuters.com/business/healthcare-pharmaceuticals/italy-give-just-one-covid-shot-some-patients-eu-struggles-with-inoculations-2021-03-04/)

Comment: And france https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-56048444

Comment: And Italy as described in the reuters link

Comment: @VicenteBolea fair enough, but it's by no means universally accepted.  My underlying point (as Tor-Einar said) is that it's the **destination** country's view on what complete vaccination involves that's important for international travel; the **originating** country's view is not material.  We don't yet know what view the US will take, **but if it decides that two doses of a double-dose vaccine are required, the fact that the country you're coming *from* thinks a single dose plus previous COVID recovery makes you fully vaccinated will be of no significance**.

Answer (score 2):

Although the rules for who exactly will be allowed to enter the US when the covid policy changes have not been finalized yet, the CDC has today published [some interim guidance on interpretation of vaccine records](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/fully-vaccinated-guidance.html#annex), which seems likely to be very close to the eventual regulations. This guidance states that

> [P]eople are considered fully vaccinated:
>
> - 2 weeks after their second dose in a 2-dose series, such as the Pfizer-BioNTech or Moderna vaccines, or
> - 2 weeks after a single-dose vaccine, such as Johnson & Johnson’s Janssen vaccine

The guidance then goes on to say that other WHO-approved vaccines, such as AstraZeneca/Oxford, are also covered under this guidance, and to provide advice for interpreting vaccination records of people who received doses of two different types of vaccine.

There is, however, no exemption mentioned for recovered people to receive only one dose of a vaccine deigned to be given as a two-dose series. Therefore, while nothing is written in stone yet, **it does not seem likely** that your friend will be able to enter the United States with their current documentation.

Answer (score -3):

Current (October 2021) policy from https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/united-states:

> There are no vaccination requirements for visitors to the United States.

Comment: That is true as for now, but starting November EU citizen will be accepted in USA as long as they are vaccinated. He is planning to come on Dec

Comment: @VicenteBolea Because we do not know the exact text of the US rules to be implemented in November, we do not know if your friend's single vaccination shot will be accepted by the US as satisfactory for entry.